# GARCH volatility modelling with external variables using R packages

Tags: r, references, garch, volatility-forecasting

I want to model stocks' volatility with GARCH based models, with external variables. Until now, I found RUGARCH package fot that purpose. However, I wonder is there any other packages for GARCH modelling with external variables. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CRAN Task View: Empirical Finance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) contains a list of finance-related R packages. You can just read the list or search the page for "GARCH" and you will find a few packages with "GARCH" as part of their name.